# php: How to resubmit (and add to) original $_REQUEST variables

Tags: php, variables, post, get, request

`jp.php?q=dog` or `jp.php?h=123&f=14` etc. Is there a better way to resubmit the arguments (other than looping through q,h,f,...) and eg add '&action=update'?
This is an attempted looped version:

```
$req_str="";
foreach($_REQUEST as $req_k => $req_v){
$req_str.=$req_k."=".$req_v."&";
}
echo "<a href=jp.php?".$req_str."&action=update >UPDATE</a>";
```

## UPDATE

I think `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is what I was looking for.

```
echo "<a href=jp.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."&action=update >UPDATE</a>";
```

Not sure though, whether this would work if variables were submitted via 'POST' rather than 'GET'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('action' => 'update')));
printf('<a href="jp.php?%s">Update</a>', $query);
```

Comment: See above: $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: @ajo See above: `http_build_query`. This way you can be sure parameters are only there once. What if there already is an `action` parameter in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`?

Comment: If there was already '&action=...', would it take the first or second value if eg 'jp.php?action=stop&q=1&action=go' ?

Comment: @ajo That's where `array_merge` comes in. The second `array('action' => ...)` will overwrite any `action` key that may already be present in `$_GET`.